# showing div before submitting form is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a form, i want to show a confirmation div BEFORE submitting it, if the user clicks ok on the new div, it submits, if not it won't, i'm using slideUp() and slideDown(), im kind if stuck, it's not working, it just redirects to the next page, how do i return true with a new button click to actually submit the form, not with the original submit button?

```
<div class="choosing" id="choosing">
  <form action="rides.php" method="POST" id="tripinfo">
    <label> Date of the trip: <br>
      <input id="date" type="date" min="2021-06-21" required>
    </label> <br>
    <button type="submit" id="subBtn" class="btn"> Finish up</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="confirmation " id="confirmation" style="display:none" ;>
  //some stuff
  <button id="ok">ok</button>
</div>
```

the script:

```
<script>

  $('#tripinfo').submit(function () {

  $("#choosing").slideDown();
  $("#confirmation").slideUp();

  if ($('#ok').click)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
    //i'm pretty sure this if statement is wrong but i don't know what is wrong with it lol.
  }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: You're missing braces in your if...else to start.

Answer (score 1):

use `event.preventDefault()` instead of return false

Answer (score 1):

You'll need cancel submitting the form with `preventDefault()` and than use different event handler to listen when user clicked on "ok" button, and only than submit the form:

```js
$('#tripinfo').submit(function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted) //check if user clicked submit button or javascript clicked it
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent submitting the form if user clicked

  $("#choosing").slideUp();
  $("#confirmation").slideDown();

});

$('#ok').click(function() {
  $('#tripinfo').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choosing" id="choosing">
  <form action="rides.php" method="POST" id="tripinfo">

    <label> Date of the trip: <br>
                          <input id="date" type="date" min="2021-06-21" required> 
                      </label> <br>

    <button type="submit" id="subBtn" class="btn"> Finish up</button>

  </form>

</div>

<div class="confirmation " id="confirmation" style="display:none" ;>
  //some stuff
  <button id="ok">ok</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i did prevent it from submitting but neither divs slided up or down, it just stays the same, what can be the issue ? and how can i add another even listener that actually submits the form? i did it like this    var form = document.getElementById('tripinfo');
      
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       $("#choosing").slideDown();
       $("#confirmation").slideUp();

});

Comment: Returning `false` from event listener does nothing, you need use `event.preventDefault()`
See my code snippet.

Comment: oh i just realized there's a code snippet and it worked like a charm, thank you very much, you're amazing

Comment: hello, i posted a new question please check it out if you can, thank you.